# MouseDragging still firing even after releasing

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt, graphics2d

Hello and thanks in advance, 
i am working with Graphics2D for a casino game (Roulette), so i am trying to add motion to the chips of the casino (The money), so for that i am using MouseDragged events and as a test i am working with only 1 ellipse.

**code below**

```
package roulette;
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class RouletteInterface extends JPanel{

    private List<Shape> money = new ArrayList<>();


    public RouletteInterface() {

        createEllipseGrap();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(300, 300);
    }



    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g4d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        paintEllipseGrap(g4d, g);
        g4d.dispose();
    }

    protected void createEllipseGrap() {
        Ellipse2D elipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(100, 100, 30, 30);
        money.add(elipse);
        addMouseListener(new moneyMouseListener());
        addMouseMotionListener(new moneyMouseListener());
    }

    protected void paintEllipseGrap(Graphics2D g3d, Graphics g) {

        g3d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g3d.fill(money.get(0));
    }

    private class moneyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
        int dragging;
        private int x;
        private int y;

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if(money.get(0).contains(e.getPoint())) {
                x = e.getX();
                y = e.getY();
                dragging = 0;
            } else {
                return ; 
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            if(dragging == 0) {
            x = e.getX();
            y = e.getY();
            Ellipse2D elipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 30, 30);
            money.set(0, elipse);
            repaint();
            } else {

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent m) {
            dragging = 1;
            repaint();
        }


    }

}



public class principal{



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new principal();

    }

    public principal() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new RouletteInterface());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

**What's the problem?** 
The MouseDragged event is still firing even after i release the mouseclick so the circle is still moving with my cursor when i click and drag on another side of the window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are adding two different instances of your moneyMouseListeners as MouseListener and as MouseMotionListener:

```
    addMouseListener(new moneyMouseListener());
    addMouseMotionListener(new moneyMouseListener());
```

You would have to do it like that:

```
    moneyMouseListener mListener = new moneyMouseListener();
    addMouseListener(mListener);
    addMouseMotionListener(mListener);
```

PS.: When using a variable like your "dragging" variable that is only used to assign a "1" or a "0" you should use a boolean variable with "true" and "false" ;)

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Also, you might want to consider drawing/undrawing the chip using XOR mode of the Graphics, rather than calling repaint() all the time.

1. Press: undraw the chip in normal mode, then xor draw it.
2. Drag: XOR draw the chip, reset the position, XOR draw again.
3. Release: XOR draw the chip, then draw in normal mode.

That way if you move the chip over something in the background (or over another chip) you don't damage the other chip or the background.